# Ble-gateway error( #90 BLEIO_gatt_read_char_by_uuid Line:155 g_tree_lookup() failed on Raspbian.)

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to connect my TI **sensortag CC2650** with **Azure IoT** instead on the registered **Watson IoT** with reference to the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-iot-edge-physical-device

I'm receiving the following error while running the gateway json config file:

> **pi@raspberrypi:~/iot-edge $ ./build/samples/ble_gateway/ble_gateway ./samples/ble_gateway/src/gateway_sample.json Gateway is running.
>   Error: Time:Thu Jun 22 15:13:37 2017
>   File:/home/pi/iot-edge/modules/ble/src/ble_gatt_io_linux_read.c
>   Func:BLEIO_gatt_read_char_by_uuid Line:151 g_tree_lookup() failed.
>   Error: Time:Thu Jun 22 15:13:37 2017
>   File:/home/pi/iot-edge/modules/ble/src/bleio_seq_linux_schedule_read.c
>   Func:schedule_read Line:114 BLEIO_gatt_read_char_by_uuid failed with
>   149. Error: Time:Thu Jun 22 15:13:37 2017 File:/home/pi/iot-edge/modules/ble/src/bleio_seq_linux.c
>   Func:BLEIO_Seq_Run Line:342 An error occurred while scheduling an
>   instruction of type 0 for characteristic
>   00002A24-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB Error: Time:Thu Jun 22 15:13:37
>   2017 File:/home/pi/iot-edge/modules/ble/src/ble.c
>   Func:on_connect_complete Line:543 BLEIO_Seq_Run failed**

I tried few approaches like running the **bluetoothctl** command and then **list-attributes** but it's still not working.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you get GATT characteristics list after running `list-attributes` command?

Comment: No. I'm not receiving any GATT characteristics list after running list-attributes command.

Comment: You can do [these instructions](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/issues/90#issuecomment-290966771).

Comment: I tried doing that. It's getting connected to my sensortag but it's not listing any attributes. According to the post, it means that my BLE environment is broken. So do I have to install blueZ again from starting?

Comment: Have you test your TI sensortag CC2650 device from other device or platform? Can you connect it successfully and read data?

Comment: Yes. I've been working on that sensortag cc2650 for two months successfully. I've been getting regular data in the Watson IoT platform. there's just one small confusion. While configuring the gateway.json file, in the logger module, the filename should be gateway.json or something else?

Comment: You can use this "build/modules/logger/log-file.log" as `filename`. Path and file name you can modify.

Comment: Tried everything. Not helping. Any more suggestions? sorry for troubling you. please help.

Comment: Maybe you can try to do a total refresh install.

Comment: thank you. the problem has been solved.